# What does "runs in the same context as" mean in this quote

Tags: command-line-interface, bitbake

In looking up CLS commands specific to DevShell (they start with ds), I found this sentence in the documentation.

"The devshell is a terminal shell that runs in the same context as the BitBake task engine." Like many definitions, you end up in an endless loop of definitions that are full of unfamiliar terms. I'm not finding much from a search.